# Affine Scaling Approach question

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Let's consider the following LP.

$$ \max z = 2x_1 + 3x_2 + x_3  $$

$$ \text{s.t. } \begin{align} \\ \\ \\ & 3x_1 + 2x_2 + 4x3 \le  7 \\
& 5x_1 -2x_3 \ge 1 \\
& x_1 + 2x_2 + x_3 = 2 \\
& x_1, x_2, x_3 \ge 0
\end{align}
$$

a) Prepare Excel spreadsheets to apply the Affine Scaling Approach to solve it. Suppose
x^(0)=[0.5,0.5,0.5]^T
 and consider  as 0.8.

b) Solve this problem by using a classical solver such as Excel solver, Gams or Lindo and
compare your results with the results in part (a).

Actually i could not use alpha on the problem, Could someone please help? [Screenshot of the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5Ef6.jpg)

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.
For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation),
[mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020),
[main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559)
and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: There is no way this can be answered here on Math.SE. For one thing, it requires the use of Excel and other software.

Comment: @MichaelGrant I understand, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After substituting the equality the problem reads

$$
\max z = x_1+x_2 + 2
$$

s.t

$$
x_1+6x_2 \ge 1\\
7x_1+4x_2 \ge 5\\
x_1 \ge 0\\
x_2 \ge 0\\
x_1+2x_2 \le 2
$$

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Cesar! So, could you please give me the initial solves of the solution? How did you reach your equalities?

Comment: @Eso Cesar Could you please show me how did you get that constrains and objective function? Thanks.

Comment: After reducing the dimension to $2$ (due to the equality substitution) the new set of restrictions define a feasible region as can be depicted in the above graphics in light blue. In red is located the objective function touching the feasible region corner which gives maximum return.